# Bonobo Git Server Authentication failed, why?

Tags: git, bonobo

I download and install Bonobo Git Server (6.0.0.532).
I have followed IIS authentication settings:

[image]

I create the repository via rescan directory.

I create the user (login: qqq, pass: qqq)

When I try to clone repository via TortoiseGit I see the followed credential window:

[image]

I put the credential of the created user [qqq, qqq]. And on this step I received the authentication error:

[image]

So the question: why it happens and how to fix it?

PS: the anonymous access (if set up it) works fine.

**UPD1**

I used commant line and *set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1* for details, but still did not get the trouble.
Command line output:
[image]

Comment: On your first picture some auths are disabled?! Enable them?

Comment: It is disabled because it is decribed in the intallation manual: https://bonobogitserver.com/install/ . But I tried different combination and it  not helps.

Comment: Do you want to use your server from extern? Or is localhost enough?

Comment: Yes, I plan to use my server externally later. At current time I just check this ability locally.

Answer (score 2):

People often solve these problems by using command line Git, and running `set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` before they do the Git clone.

This may well give you a clue what's going on.  According to your screenshot it took over 30 seconds for the `git clone` to fail, which doesn't sound like an simple authentication failure.

Comment: I still didn`t get where the trouble. See UPD1 in thу initial post for details.

Answer (score 1):

Does your password have a percent sign (%) in it?

I was having the same problem, so I downloaded the source code and traced through it.

In the `GitAuthorizeAttribute.IsUserAuthorized()` method, the username and password are retrieved from the decoded auth header by using `Uri.UnescapeDataString()`.  I had a `%42` in my password that was being converted to a `B` before attempting the authentication, which is what caused it to fail.   I changed my password so that it no longer uses a % sign and it works fine.

Note, that this is only an issue when authenticating with Git.  The percent sign in the password works perfectly fine just logging into the BonoboGitServer web application itself.

I opened an issue on BonoboGitServer's GitHub page.  https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/issues/704

Answer (score 0):

Instead of credentials qqq:qqq try admin:admin and read/choose one of

- https://bonobogitserver.com/cookie-authentication/
- https://bonobogitserver.com/windows-authentication/
- https://bonobogitserver.com/federation-authentication/
- https://bonobogitserver.com/ef-membership/
- https://bonobogitserver.com/ad-membership/

Comment: The best case for me is - https://bonobogitserver.com/ef-membership/. But it is default behaviour, the line "<add key="MembershipService" value="Internal" />" already turn on. Do I need to create new user somewhere else than bonobo git server html page?